# An array- or vector-like type with values stored on disk in Julia

Tags: julia

I am looking for an Array-like type with the following properties:

- stores elements on disk
- elements can have composite type
- elements are read into memory, not the whole array
- it is possible to write individual elements without writing the whole array
- supports `setindex!`, `getindex`, `push!`, `pop!`, `shift!`, `unshift!` and maybe `vcat`
- is reasonably efficient

So far I have found the following leads:

https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/SharedArrays/

http://juliadb.org

https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD.jl

The first one seems promising, but it seems the type of the elements has to be `isbits` (meaning a simple number, some structs but not, e.g., an `Array{Float64,1}`). And it's not clear if the whole array contents are loaded into memory.

If it does not exist yet, I will of course try to construct it myself.

Comment: `isbits` doesn't mean it can't be composite. It just means that it has to be a `struct` of `isbits` types, like a `struct` with a few complex numbers and an `Int`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the question, I hope it is correct now.

Comment: isn't this what [mmap](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/Mmap/#Mmap.mmap) is for?

Comment: I can `mmap` a multi-dimensional array of fixed size, but it isn't possible to use it for e.g. a `Array{Array{Float64,1},1}`, where the inner arrays are of variable size. It may still be the best solution though!

Answer (score 2):

NCDatasets.jl addresses part of the requirements:

- stores elements on disk: yes
- elements can have composite type: no (although some support for composite type is in NetCDF4, but not yet in NCDatasets.jl). Currently you can have only Arrays of basic types and Arrays of Vectors (of basic types).
- elements are read into memory, not the whole array: yes
- it is possible to write individual elements without writing the whole array supports setindex!, getindex, push!, pop!, shift!, unshift! and maybe vcat: just setindex!, getindex
- is reasonably efficient: the efficency is reasonable for me :-)

The project making it yourself sounds very interesting. I think it would server certainly a gap in the current ecosystem.

Some storage technologies that might be good to have a look at are:

- HDF5 (for storage, cross-platform and cross-language)
- JLD2 (successor of JLD) https://github.com/simonster/JLD2.jl
- rasdaman (a "database" for arrays) http://www.rasdaman.org/
- possibly also BSON http://bsonspec.org/

Maybe you can also reach out to the JuliaIO group.